# How to change the value of a variable dynamically, change state and update UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I need to change the value of a variable after a certain condition is met. Seems a simple problem but since I'm new to React maybe someone can help me out. I've tried several options useEffect, useRef a function with a simple if/else statement ternary operator but with no success. In the code below I need to change the value of let currentMatchDay = matchDay - 1; to let currentMatchDay = matchDay; after a condition is met, that's all.
let scheduled = program.every(match => match.status === "FINISHED"); is the conditional.
All the data is fetched from two RESTAPI's endpoints and imported from the Context and Standings components.
Thanks!

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import styles from "./styles/Recent.module.css";
import { useGlobalContext } from "./Context";
import { useGlobalState } from "./Standings";

const Recent = () => {

  const [lastGames, setLastGames] = React.useState([]);
  const [program, setProgram] = React.useState([]);

  const { state } = useGlobalContext();
  const { matchDay } = useGlobalState();

  //let scheduled = program.every(match => match.status === "FINISHED");

  let currentMatchDay = matchDay - 1   
  let upcomingGame = currentMatchDay + 1;
  let recent = state.slice(currentMatchDay - 1, currentMatchDay);
  let upcoming = state.slice(upcomingGame - 1, upcomingGame);

  const getLastGames = useCallback(() => {
    for (let games of recent) {
      setLastGames(games);
    }
  }, [recent]);

  const getProgram = useCallback(() => {
    for (let games of upcoming) {
      setProgram(games);
    }
  }, [upcoming]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLastGames();
    getProgram();
  }, [getLastGames, getProgram]);


  return (
    <>
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.matches}>
      <div className={styles.gamesnRound}>
        <div className={styles.alleWedstrijden}>Recent gespeeld</div>
        <div className={styles.speelrondes}>
          Speelronde
          <div className={styles.circle}>
            <div className={styles.dayNumber}>{currentMatchDay}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {lastGames.map((game) => {
        const { homeTeam, awayTeam, score, id } = game;

        return (
          <div className={styles.match} key={id}>
            <div className={styles.teams}>
              <div className={styles.hometeam}>{homeTeam.name}</div>
              <div className={styles.scores}>
                {score.fullTime.homeTeam} : {score.fullTime.awayTeam}
              </div>
              <div className={styles.awayteam}>{awayTeam.name}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
  </>
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display `currentMatchDay`  use can use ternary operator to do this.

```
<div className={styles.circle}>
            <div className={styles.dayNumber}>{program.every(match => match.status === "FINISHED")?matchDay:matchDay-1}</div>
 </div>
```

or use can define one function which can return `currentMatchDay` value

```
const getCurrentDay=()=>{
if(program.every(match => match.status === "FINISHED"){
return matchDay}
return matchDay-1
}

 <div className={styles.circle}>
                <div className={styles.dayNumber}>{getCurrentDay()}</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks srinivast6, I tried that before but it doesn't work. The list of matches won't update.
Only the matchDay wich is a number that shows above the list.